# How to retrieve json object at root folder of api?

Tags: javascript, php, api, post

i try to make api request process on javascript with using root folder only, and there is some problem at input read when the client side request the post through the url. i also create index.php to automaticly execute the request, here is my javascipt code with root folder url

```
function save_user(){
    var usermail = document.getElementById("emailAddress").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("usernames").value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "example.com/source/api/signup/access/";

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

and if i directly request the url to the php file it work fine without any problem, like code below

```
function save_user(){
    var usermail = document.getElementById("emailAddress").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("usernames").value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "example.com/source/api/signup/access/signup.php";

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    }
}

<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: example.com");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS");

require_once 'signup.php';

$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$cur_email = $obj->email;
$cur_name = $obj->username;

$container = new SighUp();
$respond = $container->SignupUser($cur_email, $cur_name);
echo json_encode($respond);
?>
```

is there any way to request post using root folder url only or it only can be done with direct url to the php file?

Comment: This depends on your webserver configuration. It's nothing to do with any of the code you've posted. Also if you created "index.php" to process the request then (assuming that's configured by your webserver as a default document for the folder and definitely gets executed), did you put any code in it? Because your working version calls signup.php, not index.php

Comment: P.S. I suggest testing the webserver configuration of the folder just using a simple file which can respond to a regular GET request from your browser, by simply typing the address into the browser bar and output "hello world". Then the issue of configuration isn't conflated with any potential issues relating to Javascript, AJAX, JSON or POST values. Break it down, simplify, make sure the config part works, and then move back towards making it work with your specific scenario.

Comment: @ADyson i'm using a cpanel for my webserver is there any place to check the configuration you mentioned?

Comment: @ADyson i will try your sugestion if something up i will edit the quesstion again, thank you

Comment: [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) is a hosting account management tool, not a webserver. If you're on a shared hosting environment using cPanel usually you cannot modify the core webserver config, but if it's running Apache as the webserver you can add config rules using .htaccess files in any folders you want them to apply to (it will then apply to subfolders under that normally, too). But I suggest applying it and testing it in your development environment on your local machine before you do it on your live hosting environment.